# Run opengl in c# backgroudWorker

Tags: c#, opengl

Recently, I was learning OpenGL for C#. The basic structure I need is:

Computation in UI
=> Draw OpenGL in a separate window
=> More computation in a UI.

So far, the program always freeze up in the second step (make a window, draw some stuff, and that's it). I have tried:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //Draw the image on the window
    Glut.glutIdleFunc(OnRenderFrame);
    Glut.glutDisplayFunc(OnDisplay);
    Glut.glutCloseFunc(OnClose);
    Glut.glutMainLoop();
}
```

and call

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //initialize the window, the shapes, shader, and some other stuff
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

but it does not work. I have also tried to put the code for drawing in a `button_Click` and some other, but none works so far. Can anyone please help me with that?

PS: I learn OpenGL from [GiawaVideos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2KEHrB82Z2M), in which I have also tried to ask this question, but consider their last video is 2 years ago, I don't have much hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem that BackgroundWorker can not be used to affect anything in the UI (which incidentally also include the OpenGL window). So I only have to find a way for the  to drawing code to run separately while "technically" still in the same thread via [Timer.Tick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick(v=vs.110).aspx). The code now is:

```
public Form1()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     //initialize the window, the shapes, shader, and some other stuff
     timer1.Start();
}
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //Draw stuff, not affecting the main UI thread flow
}
```